# Showing a div only on mobile devices using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a phone number div.when it is clicked, it will trigger a call,so i want to display this div only on mobile devices.for that i have assigned display none to the div initially and i am trying to show the div on mobile devices using jQuery like below

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if($(window).width() <= 480) {
        $('#phone-number').show();
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work.i didn't know what is wrong with this ,please someone help me in this issue

Comment: seems to be nothing wrong with the code. did you try `console.log($(window).width())`?

Comment: Can describe _"But it doesn't work"_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you also put your code in `$(window).resize` handler like below:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() <= 480){
        $('#phone-number').show();
    }
});
```

Also make sure that you are giving correct `id` `#phone-number`